# code,string and comments split across multiple lines

Tags: java, eclipse

While editing java code in eclipse, may be I pressed some key combo, or something else, but strings, code and comments in my entire file is now split into multiple lines. The newline is inserted at every object property/method.

```
Ex.:
object.prop1.method1()

has become:

object
   .prop1
   .method1()
```

What can I do to revert back???

**Here is one small screenshot:**

[image]

Thanx in advance...

Comment: Control-Z, or restore from source control, or set your formatting options correctly and reformat the file.

Comment: cant do first two, and in third one, what formatting options should I set?

Comment: The ones you like best ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have hit the auto formatter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. Although the formatting seems strange and would definetly not be the default. Try hitting it again and see what happens.

You can configure the formatter in the preferences under `Java`=>`Code Style`=>`Formatter`

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shfit</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>  - the short cut for format.

If have saved and ctrl + z do not work than only a new roll out from repository. If you do not have any then you can change change your format settings and perform operation one more time, but this time on your rules .

To set the format go to:

```
Options > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter
```

Comment: Should work. You can open your short cut manger to see what is assigned to format function. (ctrl + shift + L + L)

Answer (score 1):

If you press **Ctrl+Shift+F** your code gets formatted. (This must be what you pressed)
The formatter follows certain rules. You can find those rules if you go in Eclipse:

```
Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter
```

There you must edit the current profile so that you can have more characters per line. This option is in tab

> Line Wrapping  -> Maximum line width

If you set this value large enough and press again **Ctrl+Shift+F** everything is going to be restored.

Answer (score 0):

Thnx all for the suggestions....it worked by using code formatter and changing a few options

Thanx again...